# Wrapper Layout at front with alpha

Tags: android, layout

In my application I am trying to implement a unclickable wrapper layout over all the views in a layout to disable them i.e. like preview version for it so far I have done.

**XML: UPDATED**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <ProgressBar
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:theme="@style/CircularProgress"
            android:id="@+id/car_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/car_progress"
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"

            > 
     <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mega_wrapper"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <!-- all previewable views -->



 <!--  Wrapper Layout  with alpha background-->
    <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/alphaWhite"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    >

                </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>



        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

But its not working properly. as I am unable to see alpha wrapper over all my views.

Comment: take  **mega_wrapper** (relative layout) inside Wrapper Layout  with alpha background.

Comment: and inside scrollview only one parent layout

Comment: ok letme check.

Comment: unfortunately it didnot work have updated the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/car_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        />
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/car_progress"

        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mega_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <!-- all previewable views -->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <!--  Wrapper Layout  with alpha background-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#33FF0000"
        android:clickable="false"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: its already so but still it didnt work for me to add a wrapper layout above all views. however if i specify th height of layout with alphaWhite background to some value in dps it works well but its statically typed value

Comment: @MehvishFaisal you want the `Wrapper Layout` full screen or only wrap_content ? and what is alphaWhite value?

Comment: alphaWhite value is #33ffffff i.e 20% or ive also tried to specify the solid colors to check if all views are behid that layout or not but its not working for me. I want it to be full screen wrapping the overall nested layout so that it looks like preview

Comment: @MehvishFaisal I have make a test for you. it think your layout design is correct. I think the problem is 20% white is look like white

Comment: ok let me check again and thank you very much fro your concern

Comment: it worked well but views underneath are clickable even though the layout is unclickable

Comment: @MehvishFaisal if you want the underneath views unclickable you should change the property  `android:clickable="false"` of LinearLayout to `android:clickable="true"`